# AS3: Best way to register event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3

My question today is about the way we can register an event listener.

Let's say we have a `Group` element and inside it a custom `Handler` element. We want the `Handler` element to do something when `Group` triggers a custom event. Now, what is the best way to do it?

```
var group:Group = new Group();
var handler:Handler = new Handler();
group.addElement(handler);
```

Now, what is the best way to register the event listener?
1. Go on and do it from the file where we initialized the objects

```
group.addEventListener("CustomEvent", handler.handlerFunction);
```

2. Register the event listener from the Handler's class:

```
parent.addEventListener("CustomEvent", handlerFunction);
```

3. Any other way?

Comment: I am assuming they are not display objects (is that right?). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you really need to register the listeners for every object? Why don't you just invoke a method on all children when an event occurs on the 'parent'?

Comment: They are displaying objects but I just for for the sake of example I did not wrote any code here. For the second question the answer is because I want them to be loosely coupled as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Group class instance dispatch custom event directly on Handler class instance. Handler class would have an internal listener registered for example in constructor.

```
public function Handler() {
    addEventListener("CustomEvent", handlerFunction);
}
```

Group class would dispatch event following way:

```
handler.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent());
```

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of `Handler`?

Comment: I assume group has an overview about handlers. In this case loop would be used to dispatch events for all handlers. It has drawback that priority of the listener is lost. If Group doesn't have an overview about Handlers, I'd use something I call EventBus. It is an object, that is available to both Group and Handler. Group dispatches events on it and Handler attaches listeners to it.